# Programming concept

Tags: data-structures, python-3.x, string-matching

I want to make a program that sort mail from junkmail using a point--system.

For some couple of words in the mail,
I want the program to give different points for each word that I have in my program categorized as "junkwords" where I also have assign different points for different words, so that each word is worth some amount of points.

My pseudocode:

1. Read text from file
2. Look for "junk words"

   - for each word that comes up give the point the word is worth.
3. If the total points for each junkword is 10 print "SPAM" followed by a list of words that were in the file and categorized as junkwords and their points.

Example (a textfile):

```
Hello!  
Do you have trouble sleeping? 
Do you need to rest?
Then dont hesitate call us for the absolute solution- without charge!
```

So when the programs run and analyzes the text above it should look like:

```
SPAM 14p
trouble 6p
charge 3p 
solution 5p
```

So what I was planing to write was in this manners:

```
class junk(object):
    fil = open("filnamne.txt","r")
    junkwords = {"trouble":"6p","solution":"3p","virus":"4p"}
    words = junkwords

    if words in fil:
        print("SPAM")
    else:
        print("The file doesn't contain any junk")
```

So my problem now is how do I give points for each word in my list that comes up in the file?
And how to I sum the total points so that `if total_points are > 10` then the program should `print "SPAM"`,
Followed by the list of the 'junkwords' that are found in the file and the total points of each word..

Comment: Why does it print "14 p", "6 p", etc after each word? Is each word worth a different number of points? If so, this conflicts with your earlier requirement that "each word that comes up gives 1 point"

Comment: @Kevin Yes each word is worth a different number of points, forget the think abot "each word that comes up gives 1 point"

Comment: where are those points kept? Junkwords should probably be a dictionary.

Comment: Yes of course it should, should needed to change my plan know. But the real problem still remains...

Comment: If a word appears more than once does that point value get added multiple times?

Comment: @Hoopdady yes it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick script that might get you close to there:

```
MAXPOINTS = 10
JUNKWORDS={"trouble":6,"solution":5,"charge":3,"virus":7}
fil = open("filnamne.txt", "r")

foundwords = {}

points = 0

for word in fil.read().split():
   if word in JUNKWORDS:
       if word not in foundwords:
           foundwords[word] = 0
       points += JUNKWORDS[word]
       foundwords[word] += 1

if points > 10:
    print "SPAM"
    for word in foundwords:
        print word, foundwords[word]*JUNKWORDS[word]
else:
    print "The file doesn't contain any junk"
```

You may want to use `.lower()` on the words and make all your dictionary keys lowercase. Maybe also remove all non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: `has_key` has been deprecated for quite a long time in favor of `word in JUNKWORDS`.

Comment: Cool, I'll make the changes. Old habits die hard ;-)

Comment: @Hoopdady what does set() do?

Comment: It declares a set. A set is just a quick way of maintaining a unique list of things. Its how I keep up with a unique list of junkwords found in the file. If you don't want it to be unique, just change it to `foundwords = []` to make it a list and `foundwords.append(word)` to add words to it.

Comment: @Hoopdady, oh I understand know. But what if the word in my dictonary comes up more than once in the file?

Comment: It will still count the points right for the total, it just won't print out the word twice at the end. I didn't know the desired behavior there. If you want it two print twice, then just change it to a list.

Comment: @Hoopdady no I just want it to count right it doesnt need to print out the word twice at the end. I mean asume trouble comes up twice shouldnt it be 12 at the end? Cause right now it just stays the same it will just say 6 for trouble

Comment: Sorry, I meant the total count will be right. Like the total for the whole file. So if trouble is worth 6 points and trouble appears 3 times, you want it to print `trouble 18p`?

Comment: I have made the edits to make it work the way you wanted. It keeps a count of how many times each word is found and multiplies it by its value before it prints it.

Comment: @Hoopdady Thank you so much, I have just on question. How would it work if I had my dictonary in a seperated textfile?

Comment: what does the format of that file look like? You essentially have to have a standard way of defining you dictionary words. Like if you did `some_word point_value` per line. Then you would read in the file one line at a time, split that line on spaces and add your key and value to your dictionary (`JUNKWORDS[key] = value`).

Comment: @Hoopdady I mean if I have a file, like just a regular textfile of format .txt where I have my words trouble:6, solution:5 and so on. Would it work instead of having a dictonary in the program itself like your example above?

Comment: You would want to read that data in, parse it, and stick it in a dictionary for it to work with my code. If its like what you showed, it should be really easy to do that.

Comment: @Hoopdady yes I want the dictonary that we have in the code but in a separate textfile. Would you like to show how? That would be great

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25538/discussion-between-hoopdady-and-john)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
from collections import Counter

word_points = {'trouble': 6, 'solution': 5, 'charge': 3, 'virus': 7}

words = []

with open('ham.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.strip(): # weed out empty lines
         for word in line.split():
             words.append(word)

count_of_words = Counter(words)

total_points = {}
for word in word_points:
    if word in count_of_words:
       total_points[word] = word_points[word] * count_of_words[word]

if sum(i[0] for i in total_points.iteritems()) > 10:
   print 'SPAM {}'.format(sum(i[0] for i in total_points.iteritems()))
   for i in total_points.iteritems():
      print 'Word: {} Points: {}'.format(*i)
```

There are some optimizations you can do, but it should give you an idea of the general logic. [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) is available from Python 2.7 and above.

Comment: The "weeding out empty lines" would also be done by `line.split()`, so that whole loop is just `words = [w for ln in f for w in ln.split()]`.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: You must be using Python 3, just replace it with `items()`, as in `total_points.items()`, and you should change `print 'Word: {} Points: {}'.format(*i)` to `print('Word: {} Points: {}'.format(*i))`

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that each word has different points, so I have used a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).
You need to find the number of times a word in words has come in the file.
You should store the point for each word as an integer. not as `'6p'` or `'4p'`

So, try this:

```
def find_junk(filename):
    word_points = {"trouble":6,"solution":3,"charge":2,"virus":4}
    word_count = {word:0 for word in word_points}
    count = 0
    found = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.lower()
            for word in word_points:
                c = line.count(word)
                if c > 0:
                    count += c * word_points[word]
                    found.append(word)
                    word_count[word] += c
    if count >= 10:
        print '  SPAM'*4
        for word in found:
            print '%10s%3s%3s' % (word, word_points[word], word_count[word])
    else:
        print "Not spam"
find_junk('spam.txt')
```

Comment: So this is inefficient since it is cycling through words points for every line. This will become less efficient as word_points grows.

Comment: Isn't that the only way, iterating over either each word in the `file`, of each word in `junkwords`... I preferred `junkwords`.

Comment: When you do `for word in word_points` you lose the power of a dictionary's one step look up. You will be looking through tons of words that are in word_points that aren't in the file. So its better to just iterate over each word in the file and see if its in the dictionary.